# Using SMTP client on C# Exception thrown: System.UriFormatException

Tags: c#, gmail

```
            SmtpClient gclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            gclient.EnableSsl = true;
            gclient.Timeout = 10000;
            gclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            gclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            gclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "humpydogesnores");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add("username@gmail.com");
            msg.From = new MailAddress("username@gmail.com");
            msg.Subject = "Hello testing";
            msg.Body = "Hello testing ";
            gclient.Send(msg);
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully sent.")
```

I get the following error.
Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.dll
Error: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

I Just cant understand does anybody gone through this?
I am using System.Net; System.Net.Mail

I also tried MimeKit I am still getting the same error.

```
var message = new MimeKit.MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("Joey Tribbiani", "joey@friends.com"));
            message.To.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "chandler@friends.com"));
            message.Subject = "How you doin'?";

            message.Body = new MimeKit.TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = @"Hey Chandler"
            };


            using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
            {
                // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, f) => true;

                client.Connect("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate("joey", "password");

                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
```

Update 3rd.

I created a new solution and used the following code it  works successfuly. But however it simply doesn't work in my previous solution. But I badly need this in that project. I am just wondering why its happening.

```
  var message = new MimeKit.MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("Joey Tribbiani", "xx@gmail.com"));
            message.To.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "xx@gmail.com"));
            message.Subject = "How you doin'?";

            message.Body = new MimeKit.TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = @"Hey Chandler"
            };


            using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
            {
                // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, f) => true;

                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate("xx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx");

                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
```

Update 4.

Debug log of the solution that fails to send mail.

```
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\guard32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fltLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140_clr0400.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\46c6217a2d77a20d9fff301af2e1d67e\mscorlib.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Corsair\CORSAIR iCUE Software\CorsairOsdHook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\App\2Appthread\2App\bin\x86\Debug\2C.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\8cac8223556750a7b295488f7d4a74ca\System.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\ae132c7caa21b1f3a70861f13445b5a7\System.Drawing.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\6d344d1028d36aa9b960854981524682\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\b8791dcfe1d120a5766252f6cb08c3ea\System.Core.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\a3af6c9b7a8f859d5b6b79262d94c3c4\System.Configuration.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\0ed2c9bed42f40c4e5b14b89482e2248\System.Xml.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasman.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rtutils.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winhttp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OnDemandConnRouteHelper.dll'
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data\08eebc71469206e836a1ca8917f9a602\System.Data.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.17763.1098_none_b4b07e216e78aa81\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.17763.1098_none_570e5890c255915e\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsCodecs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DataExchange.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dcomp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\twinapi.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rmclient.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17763.1098_none_262365ab67c31790\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sxs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'App.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao.dll'
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wldp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\ACEDAO.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9518_none_508db366bcbd18c4\msvcr90.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Transactions\0eaf01b9523d04c3c68696587b65fc0f\System.Transactions.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\system\ole db\oledb32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msdart.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dpapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comsvcs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\srpapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\ACECORE.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.9518_none_508db366bcbd18c4\msvcp90.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\Cultures\OFFICE.ODF'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\1033\ACEWSTR.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSORES.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\davclnt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\davhlpr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\1033\MSOINTL.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#\b3413cfdcca8923f8fb206fb4bdaafe5\System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll'. 
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#\b3413cfdcca8923f8fb206fb4bdaafe5\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. 
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\schannel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mskeyprotect.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ncrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ncryptsslp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices\15.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll'. 
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices\15.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll'. 
'App.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices\15.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll'
'App.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 2C.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices\15.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.dll
Error: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.dll
Error: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
The thread 0x50e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4dec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please share the stack trace?

Comment: @OguzOzgul call stack is empty.

Comment: paste the full exception please, which is the stack trace

Comment: Obviously one of your urls cant be converted to a URI, the next question is why, who is throwing it

Comment: @learningprogram just catch the Exception (make a try/catch(Exception e) block covering all the mail sending code block) and inside the catch, do: `catch(Exception e) { Debug.Message(e.ToString()); }` or put a breakpoint there and open the exception details and copy and paste the Stack Trace of the exception

Comment: @OguzOzgul Exception thrown: 'System.UriFormatException' in System.dll
Error: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I didn't put try catch block. The code simply throws exception in the output window.  I then now trying it by putting try catch block. still it doesn't throw exception in my block but it internally throws.

Answer (score 0):

In the output log so many Cannot find or open the PDB file message appeared then. I believe it has something to do with symbols.

Cleaning the Solution and Rebuilding the project solved the issue.